# What is f:attribute used for in this example?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm trying to understand what a JSF snippet does. It goes something like this

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="field" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" default=""/>
    [...]
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
     <ui:fragment rendered="some_logic_here">
         <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
             <f:attribute name="value" value="#{cc.attrs.field.value}"/>
         </h:outputText>
     </ui:fragment>
</composite:implementation>
```

The `field` attribute refers to a `bean` member that has `getValue() / setValue()` accessors (for a string).
The `value` attribute is a string that comes from elsewhere.

From what I understand, the `output`'s value is initially set to the (static) `value` attribute: `value="#{cc.attrs.value}"`, then the `<f:attribute>` tag sets *something* to the "dynamic" value retrieved from the "field" bean.

How does this work out? Does the "dynamic" value override the static one? Always?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you guessed, this does indeed exactly the same as:

```
<h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.field.value}" />
```

In other words, the original developer didn't thought out it very well, or was fiddling until it started to work like magic, or perhaps had a short on coffee, or smoked something bad while developing.

Comment: Some testing of the original code led me to the same conclusion :)